# connectionDidFinishLoading being called before connectionDidReceiveData has received all data?

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

Im having a problem where connectionDidFinishLoading is being notified before connectionDidReceiveData has received and processed all the data. The problem is ocurring because i am trying to process the data as it arrives and update a tableview. I think this processing is slowing things down and as a result before i have processed ALL the data connectionDidFinishLoading is called and i seem to always be missing out on the last 10-15% of the data as a result.

Per the apple docs it states that the delegate will not receive any more calls after connectionDidFinishLoading is called. Is it possible that connectionDidReceiveData is not being sent all the data because it is taking a long time processing a piece of data and then connectionDidFinishLoading is called and subsequently connectionDidReceiveData isnt called again with the final pieces of data?

Fyi i tried running the data processing method in its own thread however that doesnt seem to help. Btw i had already implemented this same method in connectionDidFinishLoading which worked fine however i am trying to start processing data immediately instead of waiting for all the data to load which could take a while.

Here is the outline of the code although i have removed the processing code as it is a little long and messy.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)newData {

if (!self.data) {
    self.data = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"data is null");
}
else {
    [self.data appendData:newData];
    [self processSearchResultsForData:self.data];
}
```

Here is the method that processes the data

```
-(void)processSearchResultsForData:(NSMutableData*)newData
{

NSString *newHtmlText = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:newData.bytes length:newData.length encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

// process new data and create an array newResults with results         

// only update results array with new data if results were found
if ([newResults count] > 0) {       
    self.resultsArray = newResults;
    [self updateTableWithResults];

}
}
```

This method updates the tableView

```
-(void)updateTableWithResults
{
    // do a lot more processing here    
    // then set results array as table data source
    [self.tableView reloadData];            
}
```

thx

Comment: It's unlikely NSURLConnection class problem. Can you post your code? It's hard to guess what's wrong.

Comment: What makes you think it's missing data?

Comment: [response expectedContentLength] is not equal to length of the final converted [NSString length]. That and i also diffed the original file and the downloaded one and the downloaded one had huges chunks missing although the beginning and end were the same?????

Comment: In didReceiveData, it looks like you're ignoring the first chunk of data and then trying to fully process the data right after the second chunk comes in.  The didReceiveData method can be called multiple times and you can't really process the data until you have all of it.  Is processSearchResultsForData crashing?